# Is there any flex ("Fast LEXical analyzer") debugger out there?

Tags: debugging, gcc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm studying "Compilers" and we work on Flex to program.
I create *.lex files (with any editor), convert them into lex.yy.c via flex, and then compile to a.exe using gcc.

Writing lex code in an editor like Notepad/Codeblocks/... is not only hard because everything is just BLACK, but also there is no debugging system.
The gcc compiler does tell about errors, but what i'm looking for is something i can go line by line with the code (in runtime) and see what's going on with the variables. Like the command F10 in Visual Studio.

Does anybody know a suitable program for this? Thanks alot

Comment: For syntax highlighting use e.g. Notepad++. For debugging you can try to use gdb, or just compile it in Visual Studio. I'm not sure it makes any sense to debug a generated lexer this way though.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning hightlighting, using `gedit`(The default GUI editor on Ubuntu and some other Linux variants) or even `vim` will provide that for you, you don't have to use plain notepad.

As for the debugging, yes there's what's called the GNU Debugger (aka GDB) which allows you to do typical debugging jobs after you've compiled your code, you can step line by line and examine certain variable values.

Before doing that, first compile your program with the `gcc` flag `-g` to add debug symbols to the complied result, then run `gdb yourProgramName`, this will run GDB and you'll be able, using certain commands, to do whatever debugging tasks you want.

I once wrote [a little guide to help people get started with GDB](http://mpcadel.blogspot.com/2012/12/gdb-in-few-minutes.html), it might be useful.

Comment: OK that's great! The guide is awesome. But 1 thing missing: what if my program needs an input file at the beginning. I have a file called input.txt which will be the input. How do i make the program recieve it and then start the debugging?

Comment: You might try [xemacs](http://www.xemacs.org) on Windows, it works fine. In emacs or xemacs you can call the debugger on the executable directly from the edit buffer, and it will show how you advance along source lines (I haven't done this with flex, but it should work),

Comment: If you're using `vim`, I'd suggest you check this http://clewn.sourceforge.net/ , two points though: 1- I'd rather stick with an editor and a debugger separated, it makes me think things more thoroughly.
2- Debugging the compiled code of a lexer typically won't be that helpful

oh, and if you found the answer helpful, please click the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @vonbrand xemacs keeps saying `process error searching for program gdb` although i do have gdb installed somewhere... So maybe not in the needed place.

@AdelQodmani I didn't succeed installing vim and clewn, i found it very complicated... I gave up after spending more than an hour on it.

Comment: @vonbrand I finally solved the error. Now the problem is again how do i insert a file (i.e input.txt) for the program? normally i'd write $ ./a.exe < input.txt